# Hbase rowkey to keep track of an entity's state and avoid full table scans

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I need help with my schema design.

I have billions of entities, each entity has a static life-cycle.  Meaning an entity graduates through states `S1->S2->S3->S4`; where `S1` is the start, `S4` is the end.

A typical query would be: Show me records that are in `Sn-1` but not in `Sn`.  Most entities in `Sn-1` will reach `Sn` eventually.  I get an event every-time entity changes state.

The problem with my design is that I would have to do a full-table scan to respond to the query.

Is there a rowkey design in order to avoid full table scans?

---

Alternatively, I could change my key to: `entityId-State`

But that won't really help...

---

Another alternative would be to create a table for each State, then I could do the following:

- For entity E1 - receive event-transition-to-s1: -> put entity in Table-S1
- For entity E1 - receive event-transition-to-s2:-> delete entity from Table-S1 and add entity to Table-S2

That way when they query show me all events that in S1 but not in S2, I just show them everything in Table-S1.

The problem with this approach is that it is not idempotent.  If something happens in the system and I get the events out of order, I'll run into issues.

Comment: how large is the non-lifecycle data? or is it just entity key and states?  can the states be stored as bytes 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @MartinSerrano Yes state can be stored as number or bits in a bit map.  I'm planning to store the date of the transition, but I don't have to keep that data in HBase

Comment: any other queries?  how sensitive are you to disk space utilization?  some solutions involve storing the data in multiple ways.

Comment: @MartinSerrano - let's concentrate on that query alone.

Comment: are there really only 4 states or are there more at times?

Comment: @MartinSerrano there are a handful states < 10.

Answer (score 1):

For the query **Show me records in `Sn-1` but not `Sn`**:

*Updated for updates arrive in any order*

Make the rowkey `State-entityId`.  The column data can then be the transition date.  When writing a row for a state transition:

- check for existence of all later states for this entity, if any present, abandon update
- issue a delete for all the previous states (to handle out of order updates)
- add the new one.

In a solution like this, one has to consider simultaneous updates.  There are various strategies for handling but a full consideration requires more knowledge of the client end of your architecture.  Is it possible for state updates to arrive for the same entity at the same time?  Presumably, or they wouldn't be able to be out of order.  If so, all of the checks, deletes, and update can happen in any order.  Then the above scheme won't work without some type of external locking which is unlikely to be viable with billions of rows.

I'm presuming the number of states is small (to many states means a lot of deletes). Since the `entityId` is in the rowkey, you will presumably avoid hotspotting.

Then you can do a prefix range scan based on the desired state.  Since previous states are deleted you know that a scan for `Sn` will not (generally) have records in state `Sn+1`.  Since the delete and add cannot be done atomically there will be small windows.  But since presumably your queries are executing asynchronously from your updates (and they can be out of order), you cannot guarantee a fixed time for complete consistency for the query execution anyway.

Comment: Thanks I think as you were typing this up, I updated the question with an alternative.  In your solution, how can I account for situation where messages arrive out of order (sorry I know it wasn't part of the original problem statement).

Comment: i've got a partial solution here now, i will think some more, i need to jump in the car!